# How to select from a list in a method parameter?

Tags: c#, methods

Is there a way to choose an option from a list you created in a method's parameter?

What I mean is, if you type `Console.`, a list of possible options/actions are shown. Is it possible to do the same thing in a method?

```
static string ReturnResult (/*parameter identifier here*/ method)
{
   //do work
}
```

Say I have 3 options - Run, Sleep and Hibernate. And when I call `ReturnResult`, it'll give me those 3 options. Is that a thing?

another example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/83VJt.png . Where you see those options `COPY, DELETE, GET, etc...` is what I'm referring to.

Comment: That is an [enumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, define an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) for the parameter and it will suggest those options.

```
enum Action {
    Run,
    Sleep, 
    Hibernate
};

static string ReturnResult(Action action) {
}
```